# Add id to "contact form 7" form

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to add an id to my cf7 form. According to cf7 forum, all you have to do is to add `html_id="your id"` to the short code, but for some reason, it doesn't work.

This is my shortcode -

```
[cf7-form id="hp-top-partial" html-id="cf7-hp-top-partial" html_class="form nini-form" cf7key="question"]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13):

You can add id to any field in cf7.

```
[text* Name id:name class:input_box placeholder "Name"]
```

Comment: This was not OP's question, but it was mine :-)

Answer (score 10):

try this short code for  “contact form 7” form

```
[contact-form-7 id="hp-top-partial" title="Contact form 1" html_id="contact-form-hp-top-partial" html_class="form contact-form"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You can add any id and class to a form by adding the `html_id` and `html_class` attributes into a [contact-form-7] `shortcode`.

Example:

```
[contact-form-7 id="1234" title="Contact form 1" html_id="contact-form-1234" html_class="form contact-form"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Contact Form 7 accepts id attribute like this:

```
[text text-574 id:packagename ]
```

Comment: the name should be there before passing id param

Answer (score 0):

An id can be added to the contact form, like this:

[text* name id:result placeholder "Your Name"]

Additionally, you can convert HTML forms to CF7. Here is the website you need to visit.

[HTML to Contact form 7 Convertor](https://cf7.ciphercoin.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Show image and add Your id there

[image]

You Can add `id` in your `CF7 code` and easly give css of your contact form and it's easy way to change or access.

Answer (score -1):

Tommiz has a simple, obvious typo.
You have to write `html_id`.
He wrote `html-id`.

Comment: It already says that in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45408343/) to this same question.  Also, please don't bother with things like "why doesn't anybody else", as that might be perceived as noise.  Thanks!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32630608)